# What special characters are allowed in T-SQL column name?

Tags: t-sql, naming-conventions, naming

I would like to know what special characters are allowed to be used in column name in T-SQL, MSSQL. So I know I can use letters and numbers, but are the other characters that are available without using brackets [] to refer to this column?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx):

The first character must be one of the following:

- A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z, from A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.
- The underscore (_), at sign (@), or number sign (#).

Subsequent characters can include the following:

- Letters as defined in the Unicode Standard 3.2.
- Decimal numbers from either Basic Latin or other national scripts.
- The at sign, dollar sign ($), number sign, or underscore.

The identifier must not be a Transact-SQL reserved word. SQL Server reserves both the uppercase and lowercase versions of reserved words.

Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.

Supplementary characters are not allowed.

*edit*

refering to NinthSense: the specs also says:

Certain symbols at the beginning of an identifier have special meaning in SQL Server. A regular identifier that starts with the at sign always denotes a local variable or parameter and cannot be used as the name of any other type of object.

and this statement can be executed without errors:

```
create table #t (
  #oid int ,
  äß int,
  ßdid varchar(10),
  _data varchar(10)
)
```

Comment: This is general... for 'identifier'. Not specific to 'column names'. Think of @, #