# Error defining query in visual studio with @ character

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, I am using the wizard to create queries for TableAdapters. The query `SELECT Modell FROM BHKW WHERE Energieträger = @Energieträger` causes "Error around @ character" to appear (within the wizard). And this event though

1. the `@` and `ä` characters are [allowed characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954884/what-special-characters-are-allowed-in-t-sql-column-name) and
2. this very simple query comes from an [official Microsoft example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y0) (only the field names have been changed).

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the error? And what does you code look like? try removing the ä. It maybe allowed in TSQL, but probably isn't in C# (or VB whatever you're using)

Comment: The error does not come from the `ä`. I also tried an equivalent query `SELECT Modell FROM BHKW WHERE Hersteller = @Hersteller` that gave me the same error.

Comment: The error (translated) is "The assistant encountered the following error with your query: SELECT-Instruction has been generated. Error in the WHERE clause in the proximity of "@". Analysis of the query text impossible." I would tend to say that the error is independent from my code, as it happened into the wizard and not by compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wizard requires the use of *square brackets* for a **SQL database**. The correct query is then the following:

```
SELECT Modell FROM BHKW WHERE Energieträger = [@Energieträger]
```

If you use an Access database, the wizard will complete successfully but a warning will pop-up: "Returned data does not conform to the table's schema."

The correct syntax with an **Access database** requires a *question mark*:

```
SELECT Modell FROM BHKW WHERE (Energieträger = ?)
```