# unknown column ' column name' in 'fieldlist'

Tags: c#

I am trying to select my column `no.ofTrips` in my `tbl_bill_addtrips`
but when everytime i click the button, OK. the Unknown column '`no.ofTrips`' in 'fieldlist' appear. 
this is my sample code

```
try
    {
        string MyConSs = "SERVER=localhost;" +
         "DATABASE=prototype_db;" +
         "UID=root;";

        MySqlConnection conns = new MySqlConnection(MyConSs);
        MySqlCommand comms = conns.CreateCommand();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        comms.CommandText = "Select no.ofTrips FROM tbl_bill_addtrips WHERE RouteFrom = '" + this.txtBillRouteFrom.Text + "' and RouteTo ='" + txtBillRouteTo.Text + "'";
        MySqlDataReader Readers;
        conns.Open();
        Readers = comms.ExecuteReader();
        while (Readers.Read())
        {
            txtNoOfTrips.Text = Readers.GetValue(0).ToString();
        }
        Readers.Close();
        conns.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
    }
```

please help me thanks in advance

Comment: cross check whether you have a column name as named above. And check whether its spelled correct or not

Comment: yes, no.ofTrips is the columnName

Comment: I would follow Rob's advice. To avoid furthe problems, I would also suggest avoiding dots in column names.

Comment: Rob's right . or right click on table and select design and copy the name of the column and paste it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have table alias "no" but thats not defined in from section. 
Try this:

```
Select no.ofTrips FROM tbl_bill_addtrips no WHERE ...
```

Or remove alias from column:

```
Select ofTrips FROM tbl_bill_addtrips WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If your column name really does contain a `.` then you need to wrap it in brackets:

```
Select [no.ofTrips] FROM tbl_bill_addtrips WHERE RouteFrom ...
//     ^          ^
```

Or a backtick for MySQL:

```
Select `no.ofTrips` FROM tbl_bill_addtrips WHERE RouteFrom ...
//     ^          ^
```

Also, this code is susceptible to SQL Injection Attacks. Please have a read about [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have column name `no.ofTrips` as you are using in query. It will separate in table and column. for example no as Table name which contain ofTrips as a column. Check the column name is correct in the query.

**Solution:** Correct the `no.ofTrips` column name with allowed characters in sql.

Query many be as below:

```
"Select no.ofTrips FROM tbl_bill_addtrips as no WHERE RouteFrom = '"....
```

here `no` is made as abbrivation of the `tbl_bill_addtrips` that may be you are missing..

Check this - [What special characters are allowed in T-SQL column name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954884/what-special-characters-are-allowed-in-t-sql-column-name)

Answer (score 0):

its happening because your column name consists of a '.' try renaming your column to no_of_Trips or no_ofTrips as because of . it takes 'no' as a table and 'ofTrips' as a column

you can also use [] around column name as [no.ofTrips]